# Finding permission Group Name from permission Name Android

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

I need to find the permission group name like Contacts,Storage etc from the permission name. I have the following code

```
public ArrayList<String> permissionGroup(ArrayList<String> permission) {
    ArrayList<String>groupPermission = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    for(String entry : permission){
        PermissionGroupInfo info = null;
            try {
                info =pm.getPermissionGroupInfo(entry,0);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.w("infoerror ", e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
                if(info == null){
                    Log.w("infonull","error");
                }
                else {
                    String loadLabelVal = info.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                    Log.w("groupName ", loadLabelVal);
                    if (!groupPermission.contains(loadLabelVal)) {
                        groupPermission.add(loadLabelVal);
                    }
                }
    }
    return groupPermission;
}
```

Here the input to te function is an arraylist of permissions for which the corresponding group needs to be found. Am getting pm.getPermissionGroupInfo(entry,0) as null. 
I dont know what is the mistake. Pls correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

To get the "Short name" for example the "**Location**" you can use

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
PermissionInfo permissionInfo = packageManager.getPermissionInfo(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 0);
PermissionGroupInfo permissionGroupInfo = packageManager.getPermissionGroupInfo(permissionInfo.group, 0);
Log.w("11_APP", ""+permissionGroupInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
```

Comment: In Android 10, packageManager.getPermissionInfo throws NameNotFoundException